# Optimization of ObjectOutputStream & ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, sockets, object, tcp

I have done some Google Fu and have found that

```
os = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Greatly improves the speed of sending objects over a socket in Java, although I have not found any other ways of optimizing sending objects over sockets. My objects are serialized and I avoid creating new instances of these objects so they are not re-serialized.

What I do is I broadcast these objects over to all connected clients. As the amount increases the speed of completing the broadcast greatly decreases. I am unsure if it is the cause of the client having a slow/unstable connection or if it due to the code not being optimized. I cannot find any other way of optimizing sending objects over sockets other than what has been mentioned above.

EDIT: I am broadcasting the objects by iterating through the connected clients list and sending each object one by one. I have tried to send all the objects in one but have failed to read it from the client side (Seperating the objects). I have come to think that it was not possible but if it is, please let me know and I will continue with my trial-and-error to get that method working.

Can anyone point me to the right direction as to what might be decreasing my performance?